# Gson - Why does my loop mess up my json file?

Tags: java, json, gson, writetofile

This is my "example.json" before I run my code:

```
{
  "example1": {
    "example2": {
      "example3": 30
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this code:

```
JsonManager.writeString("example", "example1", "example2", "example7", "70");
```

This function:

```
public static void writeString(String fileName, String ... objects) throws IOException {

    Path jsonFile = Paths.get("src/" + fileName + ".json");

    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(jsonFile);
         BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(jsonFile, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        JsonObject value = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class);
        
        // Method 1:
        
        value.getAsJsonObject(objects[0]).getAsJsonObject(objects[1]).addProperty(objects[2], objects[3]); //
        
        // Method 2:
        
        String property = null;
        int i = 0;

        for (String s : objects) {
            i++;
            if (i == objects.length) {
                value.addProperty(property, s);
            }
            if (i == objects.length - 1) {
                property = s;
            } else {
                value = value.getAsJsonObject(s);
            }
        } //

        gson.toJson(value, writer);

    }

}
```

Now method 1 in the function above works as intentional does this to "example.json":

```
{
  "example1": {
    "example2": {
      "example3": 30,
      "example7": "70"
    }
  }
}
```

Method 2 does this to "example.json":

```
null"example1": {
    "example2": {
      "example3": 30,
      "example7": "70"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening and I've tried multiple times to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors here:

- the actual cause of your problem: at the last execution of the loop, `value.addProperty` is called, and then the `if` goes down and the `else` block is executed, causing your result. Just change second `if` to `else if` or add a break after `value.addProperty`.
- this is still not gonna work well after that fix, because you are overwriting the `value` variable (which you don't do in method 1). Try the first fix and see what happens, you will have 'double json' in your file. Fix is simple: just write the original value, not the one after operations.

```java
JsonObject value = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class);
JsonObject originalValue = value;
...
gson.toJson(originalValue, writer);
```